# Add blanks to importrange data

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have a single column of around 35 entries of data. I want to use the importrange formula to copy the data to a different workbook. Each data entry needs to be in different columns spaced out evenly. eg

my column of data:

data 1

data 2

data 3

data 4

needs to be in one row like this:

data 1 blank blank blank data 2 blank blank blank data 3 etc.

I know to use transpose but I cannot use the split function as the data entered could be anything and there are not clear delimiters (the data is some written work entered by a user). How can I add blanks between each data entry?

Answer (score 0):

- Use 4 skulls(with space) as delimiter
- JOIN and SPLIT the given range `A1:A4` by the skull
- IMPORTRANGE the resulting columns

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(REPT("☠ ",4),1,A1:A4),"☠"))
  ```

Comment: Thanks it works. The sheet that this formula will run on is quite small and compact. This formula will be hidden but it throws out the symmetry of the sheet. Is there a way to use the formula result without it populating the cells in the workbook? Or a way to keep the result hidden after a number of columns?

Comment: @ck8 Look into `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()`

Comment: Thank you again, exactly what I need.